# How can I include a javascript file using php echo?

Tags: php, javascript

How can I include a javascript file using php echo ?

I am creating a html page using php ---

```
echo "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' <script src="Calculation.js"> </script>  href='style.css' </head><body>";
```

I have included script code in the above line and then in form tag ---

```
<form action='/workdonecalculation/index.php?_pagination_off=1' method='post'  class='form'  onSubmit='return workdone();'>
```

But my php code doesn't call my javascript file (Calculation.js)

Comment: You *can't* call a JS file. You can call a function defined in that file.

Comment: Come on, there are myards of examples for this. You need to echo a reference to the javascript file inside the head section of your html page.

Comment: echo '<script src="URL_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT"> </script>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close `<link>` tag and `<script>` tag misplaced inside `<link>` tag. Also you need to escape the double quotes in `src="Calculation.js"` or simple you enclose with single quotes.

Here is the correct code,

```
echo "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' /><script src='Calculation.js'></script> </head><body>";
```

Comment: Welcome machi. By the way don't forget to set correct Answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
 echo "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/> <script src='Calculation.js'></script>"
```

First close link tag, and you are using double quotes.. for the src= use single, because you are already using double in the echo  "". So **src='Calculation.js'**

Also
you can do this the easy way use variables.

```
$a=<<<HERE
<script src="Calculation.js"> </script>
HERE;
echo $a;
```

Also you can close php and start html where ever you wish

```
<?php
if($i)
{
?>
<script src=""></script> 
<?php
}
?>
```

Is that what you wanted???

Comment: No, I din't close the link tag "/>" and that was the problem. Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to complete link tag first.

Try this

```
echo "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' /> <script src='Calculation.js'></script>  </head><body>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the link tag is not closed properly and the double quotes in script tag is not escaped.

Try the below code :

```
echo "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'><script src='Calculation.js'></script></head></html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

use single qoute:

```
echo '<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> </head><body>';
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
print("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"Calculation.js\"></script>");
```

Are you running this code on Windows, if not are you sure the file is called "Calculation.js" and not "calculation.js"? Also, is it definitely in the same directly as the PHP script that's calling it?