# how to call jquery function in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a project and my problem is calling a jQuery function like this placing it in my php file. I've tried searching a lot but I'm always coming out with an error:

Function:

```
$(function(){
 $(".panorama-view").panorama360();
 });
```

Php file

```
<?php

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/panorama360.css" rel="stylesheet" >';
echo '<script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" ></script>';
echo ' <script src="/js/jquery.panorama360.js" ></script>';
echo '<script>  $(function(){ $(\'.panorama-view\').panorama360(); }); </script>';
echo '</script>';

 if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

 $image_name= $_FILES['image']['name'];
 $image_type= $_FILES['image']['type'];
 $image_size= $_FILES['image']['size'];
 $image_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

 if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"uploadedimg/$image_name"))
 {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('File Uploaded!');</script>";
 }
$folder= "uploadedimg/";
if(is_dir($folder)) {

    if($handle = opendir($folder)){
        while(($file= readdir($handle)) !=false){
            if($file === '.' || $file === '..') 
                continue;
            echo '<div class="panorama round" style=" width:1200px; height:500px; padding:10px ;background-color:#444; position: relative;">';
            echo '<div class="panorama-view">';
            echo '<div class="panorama-container">';
            echo '<img src="uploadedimg/'.$file.'" data-width="4077" data-height="500" alt="Panorama" />';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
         closedir($handle);
    }   
}     
} ?>
```

Comment: you can _not_ call a client side function from a server side script. But you _include_ javascript depending on php code.

Comment: please be more specific: which jQuery function do you want to call based on which php-state/action/... And what error do you get now?

Comment: i want to call this function: $(function(){
 $(".panorama-view").panorama360();
 });

Comment: when do you want to "call" this function?

Comment: i've tried putting the function in the php file in this way but im messing up in someway here: echo '<script>  $(function(){ $('.panorama-view').panorama360(); }); </script>';

Comment: that's alright! What error did you get?

Comment: this is the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '').panorama360(); }); </script' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\php\upload.php on line 7

Comment: i want to call it when im previewing my image after uploading

Comment: you need to escape the quotes `'` inside the js-code with `\\`` like this: `echo '<script> $(function(){ $(\'.panorama-view\').panorama360(); }); </script>';` or use double quotes `...(".panorama-view")...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Echo - Escaping quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593049/php-echo-escaping-quotes)

Comment: i've made your edits but its still not working

Comment: "still not working" means what exactly?

Comment: an you please edit your post and add the line where you are echoing the JavaScript?

Comment: @jeff im getting an error

Comment: @EhsanT Post is edited

Comment: First of all, you can use double quotes so you do not need to escape single quotes like this: `echo '<script>$(function(){ $(".panorama-view").panorama360();});</script>';` and second, Please be as more specific as you can. What do you mean be _getting an error_. Still getting the same error as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '').panorama360(); });...`? at same line?

Comment: also you have an extra `echo '</script>';` line in your code which you have to delete it

Comment: I've edited my code accordingly but now i'm getting different errors, You can check them from this link [(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6OEpFdnBDN3QzWXM/view?usp=sharing)] And the JQuery error im getting it from two other js files i got them from an internet to help me but i didnt want to upload them as it would be too much code? Please never mind me as i am a beginner in php html & javascript and a new user in Stackoverflow

Comment: @menna: I've checked your Google Drive screenshot about the error you are facing; do check my post below for an effective resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get **`Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`** or **`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`** error *(as seen in your shared [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6OEpFdnBDN3QzWXM/view) in comments under your post)* because you have not included the jQuery library in your project.

*Both errors are identical and pointing to the same problem as explained above.*

Note that you CANNOT use *panorama360* without making use of the jQuery library as it (jQuery library) is a required dependency.

To include the jQuery library in your project, you have two (2) main options; either:

You consume it from a content delivery network (CDN) by including it in your project as shown in the snippet below,

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

or,

downloading and referencing it directly from your stored location

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

There is a last option which has to do with combining the earlier two mentioned above, using one as a graceful failover; here is the illustration:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

*(With the above, you can make use of the jQuery library in your project by consuming it from the CDN and automatically load the version on your sever should the later fail. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39304351/6381711))*

It's important to note that your jQuery library declaration SHOULD occur before the referencing of your panorama360 JavaScript resources; either:

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.panorama360.js" ></script>
```

Should you chose to use PHP **`echo()`** function to handle your file inclusion, do use a single quote or escape your double quotes. *... more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12745203/6381711).*

So, you should be doing something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/panorama360.css'>";
echo "<script
    src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'
    integrity='sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8='
    crossorigin='anonymous'></script>";
echo "<script src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>";
echo "<script src='/js/jquery.panorama360.js'></script>";
echo "<script>$(function(){ $('.panorama-view').panorama360(); });</script>";
```

To reference your resources without making use of PHP the raw HTML way as discussed in comment below,

```
<?php
    // Should you want to run any PHP codes before referencing your resources,
    // you may do so here.
    // Remember: you MUST close this section as below this comments so as to
    // mark the end of your PHP code
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/panorama360.css">
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.panorama360.js"></script>
<script>$(function(){ $('.panorama-view').panorama360(); });</script>

<?php
    // Here, other PHP codes
?>
```

Comment: Phewww thankyouu very much but i would just ask for a last thing if i am linking a .css file in my php file is it possible to do so? and if yes is this syntax of linking is correct? `echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/panorama360.css'>";`

Comment: Yes; it is possible. Using PHP **`echo()`** function as illustrated in the last example above, you can achieve that just as you've did in your comment right above, where the value of your `href` attribute ought to be the path to your resource *(desired stylesheet)*.
You can equally do that the plain HTML way without having to use PHP for both CSS and JavaScript file inclusions should you desire to do so. Updating my answer with an example to that effect.

Comment: And unfortunately im getting this error in this jquery file [(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6bmw1TUJUdG9VbE0/view?usp=sharing)]

Comment: Please post a new question with that error as it isn't related to this current one and link it up here so I could check it up. Remember to post your current code as it were when you encountered that error.

Comment: @menna: Any progress *(relating to your last shared [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qEe3DyVcm6bmw1TUJUdG9VbE0/view?usp=sharing)) above)*?

Comment: Yes i've posted a question and thanyou for your reply  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224280/insert-jquery-function-in-php-file-uncaught-typeerror()]